# How to open Chrome/Win10 in EXCLUSIVE fullscreen mode as opposed to screen sized borderless window?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, browser, vsync

There are multiple flags around involved with starting Chrome in fullscreen and unlocking high framesrates and low input lag

```
--start-fullscren
--kiosk
--app
--disable-gpu-vsync
--disable-frame-rate-limit
```

However AFAIK no combination allows Chrome on Windows 10 to start in "Exclusive Fullscreen" mode. It seems that it's only possible to start Chrome in a screen-sized borderless window.

I also switched between different graphics backends (OpenGL, D3D9, D3D11) - no difference.

Running in a borderless window instead of exclusive fullscreen forces Windows DWM to remain active which causes triple buffering and introduces an additional lag of at least one display refresh cycle (16ms if your display is 60Hz).

How can I open Chrome in exclusive fullscreen mode on Win10 so that I can get lower input lag?